# Chef: Format and mount device

Tags: chef-infra

I need to perform these instructions in order to mount a device:

```
mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-0DO_Volume_baz

mkdir -p /mnt/baz;
mount -o discard,defaults /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-0DO_Volume_baz /mnt/baz
echo /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-0DO_Volume_baz /mnt/baz ext4 defaults,nofail,discard 0 0 | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

Shortly, I need to format the device and then mount it.

Is it possible to do that using chef?

Answer (score 1):

You can use community [filesystem cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/filesystem)

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else you can use a `bash` resource to run whatever you want. But in this case it would probably be easier to use a `directory` resource and a `mount` resource. The `mkfs` command is a bit harder to deal with since you only want to run that if the device isn't already initialized. You can usually use other commands to check for idempotence but the specifics depend on your use case (an `execute` resource with an guard clause is probably what you want).